# R help Install archived package 'bi0ps' could not find libtiff

Tags: r, homebrew, cran, libtiff

I'm trying to install the archived R package`bi0ps`. I downloaded the tar.gz file from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/biOps/. I'm trying to install biOps_0.2.2.tar.gz.

When I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
install.packages('/Users/eholdridge/Downloads/biOps_0.2.2.tar.gz',type="source")
inferring 'repos = NULL' from 'pkgs'
* installing *source* package ‘biOps’ ...
** package ‘biOps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fftw3.h usability... no
checking fftw3.h presence... no
checking for fftw3.h... no
configure: WARNING: Can't find fftw3 header
checking jpeglib.h usability... no
checking jpeglib.h presence... no
checking for jpeglib.h... no
configure: WARNING: Can't find libjpeg header
checking tiff.h usability... no
checking tiff.h presence... no
checking for tiff.h... no
configure: WARNING: Can't find libtiff header
checking for jpeg_destroy_compress in -ljpeg... no
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
Try static libs needed on OS X
checking for TIFFOpen in -ltiff... no
Error: Could not find libtiff.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘biOps’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/biOps’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/eholdridge/Downloads/biOps_0.2.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried to fix this error by installing `libtiff` with Homebrew:

```
brew install libtiff
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libtiff-4.0.6.el_capitan.bo
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libtiff-4.0.6.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring libtiff-4.0.6.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.6: 259 files, 3.4M
```

But I still get the same error as reported above when I try to install `bi0ps`. I'm working in R Studio using version:

```
version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          2.2                         
year           2015                        
month          08                          
day            14                          
svn rev        69053                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
nickname       Fire Safety
```

Mac OS X El Capitan. My best guess is that its either has something to do with the headers (based on the warnings) or that R is looking for libtiff in the wrong directory. Any help with this error would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to intsall fftw library too. Try installing fftw and then retry installing biOps